# Как изменить высоту градиента с помощью phpimagick?

Tags: php, imagick

Использую библиотеку Imagick. Хочу изменить высоту градиента повыше. Как это можно сделать?

```
<?php
$im = new Imagick('save.png');

if (!$im->getImageAlphaChannel()) {
$im->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SET);
}

$refl = $im;

$gradient = new Imagick();

$gradient->newPseudoImage($refl->getImageWidth(), $refl->getImageHeight(), 'gradient:transparent-orange');

$refl->compositeImage($gradient, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);

$canvas = new Imagick();

$width = $im->getImageWidth();
$height = $im->getImageHeight();

$canvas->newImage($width, $height, 'none');
$canvas->setImageFormat('png');

$canvas->compositeImage($im, imagick::COMPOSITE_SRCOVER, 0, 0);
$canvas->compositeImage($refl, imagick::COMPOSITE_SRCOVER, 20, $im->getImageHeight());
$canvas->writeImages("new.png", true);
?>
```

Comment: Вероятно, используя другие значения вместо getImageWidth и getImageHeight?

Comment: Этот момент изменяет только местоположение градиента. К примеру, если увеличить Height, то он поднимется. Но отступ снизу будет.